# Cannot received events in hyperledger composer 0.19.3 client

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using hyperledger composer 0.19.3 with hyperledger fabric 1.1. I have a composer client app and I am trying to listen for events from a transaction that emitted the event. I can see the event in the historian within the composer rest server. However the debug trace log shows the following over and over again "could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events...". The code is as follows:

This client app is modeled off the sample digitalProperty land title example.

```
listen() {
        LOG.info('Awaiting events');
        this.bizNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {
            // event: { "$class": "org.namespace.BasicEvent", "eventId": "0000-0000-0000-000000#0" }
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Given this isn't the grpc problem, then there is a problem at business network connection time where it cannot connect to the event hub. Some possible reasons for failure could be the event url definition is incorrect, the identity used to connect to the event hub is not valid. 
Could you paste more detail here about your hlf setup, connection profile and card you are using to connect with.

Comment: This example is using the connection profile from the tutorial network and is using the fab-dev-servers prereq setup. export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11

./downloadFabric.sh
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh

Do I also need to export the FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11 in the same shell before starting the composer client?

Comment: Looks like once I export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11 in the shell window where my composer client runs, I now receive the events. Is this correct that you need to also set this env variable for composer client? If so, would you also need to set it for the compose-rest-server?

Comment: FABRIC_VERSION only has meaning for our fabric-dev-servers development hyperledger fabric network. It doesn't have any meaning elsewhere